# file deletion from NTFS drives doesn't frees the space on the disk

Tags: macos, mac, ntfs

Okay, so this problem is very weird.
I have rMBP mid 2014 running OS X El Capitan and Paragon NTFS 14 software, which enables write premission for NTFS drives.
There's no problem with copying files to/from NTFS usb sticks.
However - when I try to delete a file, it dissapears, but the space it was taking is not freed, but remains marked as "used".
Check example below:

I copy 6.2 gb file onto disk. Remaining space is 18.5gb out of 24.7, which is correct:

[image]

2. Now I delete that file, but remaining space is still 18.5gb:

[image]

<strike>The only way to free that once used space, is to format the drive.</strike>  (I found solution but still need help, check comments below)

- I've tried to use both windows and terminal on OS X to format the drive (sudo diskutil eraseVolume UFSD_NTFS LABEL /dev/diskXsY).
- I've checked the drive for errors using diskutil.
- On windows this problem doesn't exist, and drive works properly.
- I've tested another drive with NTFS file system, which showed same issue.
- This problem also existed on OS X Yosemite
- Device used: USB 3.0 32gb goodram usb stick, and USB 2.0 4gb usb stick

**partical solution**
Okay so I found out that when I "delete" a file from ntfs drive it's not deleted, but moved to trash instead. Therefore amount of space that file took is still locked on the drive. In order to release it, all you have to do, is empty trash while the drive is mounted.

So now the Q is: Is there a way to force Mac to delete files from external drives permanently & skip  the trash?

Comment: Does this same behavior happen if you use Windows to delete the file?  If it does not then it sounds like a problem with `Paragon NTFS 14` and should be reported to Paragon.  Be sure you are running the current version of `Paragon NTFS 14`.

Comment: Hey @Ramhound  ! As I mentioned in the post, this behavior doesn't happen on Windows. I also thought that it's paragon software related issue, but then I discovered one thing: When I "delete" a file from a NTFS drive, it's actually not being deleted, but moved to trash instead. Because of this, the size of deleted file is still locked on the drive. Once the trash is emptied, the space on the NTFS drive is released. So now the question is: Is there a way to force mac to skip trash when deleting files from external drives, to avoid such behavior?

Comment: You have reported this issue to Paragon?

Comment: @Ramhound Yup, but they weren't able to help me. They didn't even want to troubleshoot this problem, they just said: use the software as usual, it has built-in tools. >.<